# What's the equivalent of Linux's updatedb command for the Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, locate

If I want to use the `locate` command on a Linux machine, I usually run `sudo updatedb` first to update the database. I can run the `locate` command on OS X 10.5 but I can't find `updatedb`.  What's the corresponding updatedb for the mac?

Comment: Well upatedb and locate are nice things but they require to run updatedb regularly (either updatedb runs regularly and this slows down your system at inconvenient times, or locate shows references to files which are not there anymore). So I think that instead of setting up locate/updatedb it would perhaps be better to get familiar with (the far more powerful) find.

Comment: While find is useful for lots of things, it does need to go through the filesystem each time.  If you can narrow down the places where you are looking, that's fine.  The advantage of locate is that keeps its own database, and so doesn't need to search each time.  This is especially important with large and/or remote filesystems. 
I think that each has its place.

Comment: When first running `locate` on an OS X box it tells you to run `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`.

Comment: Depending on what you need to use `locate` for, you might find it more convenient to use the command line interface to Spotlight, `mdfind`, since the Spotlight database is nearly always up-to-date, and offers a lot more functionality than locate. `man mdfind`

Comment: The answer to this question is found in `man locate`  :)  The answer has been in `man locate` since **at least** August 17, 2006.

Answer (score 388, accepted):

It's `locate.updatedb` on Mac.

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

For more information see the [**locate.updatedb man page**](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/locate.updatedb.8.html).

Comment: That `man` page also claims: *It is typically run once a week by the /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist job.* (And `man locate` tells one about that script:
*/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb Script to update the locate database*)

Comment: @Arjan : It should be run once a week, but the default it's disabled and the time when it should be done is 3am on Sundays (or something similar), which isn't really useful :)

Comment: On linux I usually run `sudo ionice -c3 updatedb` which tells `updatedb` to share the i/o controller nicely (io nice) but I don't think this command is available on mac. I also miss having the `-r` regular expression flag which can be used with the GNU locate, although I'm not sure I want to use homebrew and install the GNU locate mentioned by @Grogs

Comment: Example macosx alternative to "locate (-r)" and "updatedb" that uses spotlight ("-i" optional of course): mdfind -name "mp4" | egrep -i "^/Users.*Downloads/.*Stuff"

Comment: Also, if you *don't* find files which you expect to, note this relevant caveat from the the BUGS section of  the [manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/locate.1.html):

`The locate database is typically built by user ''nobody'' and the
 locate.updatedb(8) utility skips directories which are not readable
 for user ''nobody'', group ''nobody'', or world.  For example, if your
 HOME directory is not world-readable, none of your files are in the
 database`

Comment: f you get `shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied` `cd` to your home directory, i.e. `cd ~`

Comment: On MacOS Sierra if you get the permission denied error try going to root `cd /` and then executing the `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`.

Comment: @michael thank you for pointing out that `mdfind` is an alternative to using `locate` on Mac OS.

Comment: **NOTE:** patiently wait for the command to finish. There's no output when running the command, making it feel like it's not working, but it is. Just wait.

Answer (score 106):

You can do `sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb /usr/local/bin/updatedb` to make the `updatedb` command available.

Comment: Heh, I just posted this as a comment.. Then saw you said this. I think this is a nice little mod to make. :)

Comment: or alias it in your .bash_profile

Answer (score 24):

Personally, I just installed findutils (use MacPorts or Homebrew).

Then you have GNU locate and updatedb.

updatedb won't work without sudo.

Personally I prefer to have a per user locatedb though; if you sudo other users will know the names/locations of all your files.

I have a cron job to run:

`updatedb --localpaths='/Users/grogs' --output='/Users/grogs/tmp/locatedb'`

And in my .zshrc .bashrc/.bashprofile:

`export LOCATE_PATH="~/tmp/locatedb"`

Comment: Brew-installing findutils on OS X Mavericks gave me a `gupdatedb` command, not an `updatedb` one. Unfortunately this command gave me [an error described here](http://www.rubycoloredglasses.com/2012/03/locate-and-updatedb-with-homebrew/) (where your SO answer is referenced). Ultimately I've aliased `updatedb` to `LC_ALL=’C’ sudo updatedb` as a workaround, but I don't know if this is a long-term solution.

Comment: Add `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin` at the start of your path, if you want the `coreutils` and `findutils` installed by `macports` to be available with their original names (and not their `g`-prefixed versions).

Comment: I've recently installed the Linux version of `locate` from MacPorts. Unfortunately, the `updatedb` port is **broken**, which of course renders the newer Linux version of `locate` as useless.

Answer (score 5):

If you run locate without first updating the database, you have a chance to see the OS's recommended way by its output.

```
WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once 
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use the GNU locate & update in mac too.

```
brew install findutils --with-default-names

export PATH="$(brew --prefix findutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$(brew --prefix findutils)/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"

which locate
```

Comment: _or_ to avoid the name collision with the macos ootb `locate` install _without_ the `--with-default-names` switch and then invoke via `glocate`