# Strange 'locate' behavior and icon changing

Tags: icons, locate

I'd like to change the icon of a program called Refit with a custom one. This program has various tools and when I try to change those icons all is ok but then I run the following command:

```
$ locate refit.icns
```

and the output is:

```
$ /efi/refind/icons/os_refit.icns
```

The problem is that I don't have any folder called refind and the path simply doesn't exist. I tried it with both:

```
$ ls
```

and

```
$ sudo ls
```

in the /efi directory. So my questions are actually two: how can I change the icon of that program? And why there is this strange behavior with the locate command?

I'm on Snow Leopard 10.6.8. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `locate` command works off of a database, so if you *used to* have a file called `/efi/refind/icons/os_refit.icns`, `locate` might continue to report that file as an option even after the file has been deleted. The `updatedb` utility updates the `locate` database. This program should be run periodically. Typing `sudo updatedb` should run it immediately -- but be aware that this will take a while (probably a couple of minutes) to run, and it's rather disk-intensive.

A caveat: My Mac is powered into Linux at the moment, so I'm basing this on Linux utilities. OS X is usually quite similar at this level, but it's possible there are some critical differences.

Comment: your answer is correct but you should update it for the mac case. The command is sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb according to [this answer on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/109590/whats-the-equivalent-of-linuxs-updatedb-command-for-the-mac). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Locate can be configured to look for mounted and unmounted partitions. I'll admit that I have no experience with locate in OS X (run `locate -V` to get some info), but I'll guess that you will find that some sort of boot partition is being scanned and indexed by locate if you look at the configuration file. It may be located in /etc/locate.conf. If it's not there, then do a `man locate` and scroll down to **FILES**. If you find only the mount-point there (ie /efi), then /etc/fstab is the place to look for the associated device.

Comment: I don't understand, if I have deleted the refind folder, in which partition it exists? When I run $locate 'a file I'm sure it's in my home' it finds it immediately so I guess it is scanning the right partition.